# Java - Can not create objects in a shortend line if

Tags: java

Lately I started programming in Java again after a short break and whilst doing a project for a friend I noticed something odd: It appears you can not create objects in shortened ifs, example:

```
if( condition )
     Statement statement = con.createStatement();
```

(I cut the code short for simplicity's sake.)

I receive an error saying that `Statement` (a class from the `java.sql` package) can not be resolved to a variable, however, if I were to wrap the code with braces it would work fine.

I assume this is some problem with the compiler turning this in to a multiline statement but I'm uncertain, I'd like to know the reason for this behaviour, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a full eample please?

Comment: That has something to do with `statement`'s `scope`!!! Please post the relevant code to clarify more,cutting short the code won't help us!

Comment: Yes I am sure adding braces fixed the problem, yes I have imported the required classes.

Full example:
`if( ! (con == null) )
     Statement statement = con.createStatement();`

Gives an error whilst:

`if( ! (con == null) ){
     Statement statement = con.createStatement(); 
}`
Works fine

Comment: Well, I tried similar code : `if (i > 3) String str = "aaa";`. I got a different error - `error : not a statement`.

Comment: And this is why you should always use `{}` in your *if statements*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't declare a variable there (the current error, from Java 8, is `error: variable declaration not allowed here`). If you think about it, it makes sense: You haven't created a new scope (but using a block), but you're creating a situation where sometimes in the current scope, there will be a `statement` variable, and other times there won't. E.g.:

```
if (condition)
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();

// Does `statement` exist here? What would Schrodinger say?
```

If you use a block, it clarifies the matter: The variable exists, but only within the block.

```
if (condition) {
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    // `statement` exists here
}
// `statement` does not exist here
```

If you want `statement` to exist in the current scope, you have to separate your declaration from your initialization:

```
Statement statement;

if (condition)
    statement = con.createStatement();
```

But then you run into the issue that `statement` **may** not have been initialized. To avoid that, you have a couple of options:

```
Statement statement;

if (condition)
    statement = con.createStatement();
else
    statement = null;
```

or

```
Statement statement = condition ? con.createStatement() : null;
```

Or of course, just use the block and only use `statement` within it. FWIW — and this is totally up to you — I (and many style guides) recommend *always* using blocks, because not doing so can introduce maintenance issues when you need (inevitably!) to add a second statement to the body of the `if`...

Comment: This is quite intriguing, thank you for the clarification @T.J.Crowder !

Comment: I like how I never knew this. I guess that's one of the perks of following standards. :)

Answer (score 2):

As per [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html),

```
  A local variable, one of the following:
       A local variable declared in a block (§14.4)
       A local variable declared in a for statement (§14.14)
```

If you don't wrap the statement within braces, it immediately falls out of scope.

More info here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9206679/978501