# Why can't we use declarative statement after while loop without curly braces?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, iteration, declaration

Without using curly braces why can't we use declarative statement after `while` loop?

With Curley braces it compails :

```
while(true){
    int u =89;
}
```

Without curly braces, a compile-time error occurs:

```
while(true)
    int u =89; // compile time error
```

Comment: I don’t know why a compile time error would occur, but why are you declaring something in a one statement scope? The declaration of `int u` uses up your single statement. You would not be able to use it, inside, or outside, of the scope.

Comment: yeah, no use of declaring a single statement but it's a tricky interview question. I'm trying to find the WHY part of every single code. there might be a reason for the compile-time error. thanks for the comment

Comment: Welcome! Sorry I couldn’t be of more help. Good luck though.

Comment: Thanks mate! yeah better if we find reason for every single code

Comment: The same happens with `if`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206618

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntactical reason is that the element after the `while` statement is `statement`, which includes all the executable statements, and specifically blocks, but does not include declarations.

The design reason is that it wouldn't make the least bit of sense. The scope of the declared variable would terminate at the concluding semicolon, so the declared variable  would be of no possible use in the succeeding program text.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a look into the grammar of Java found on oracle.com: [Chapter 18. Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html).
(I hope it is the correct version which applies to the question.)

> ```
> Statement:
> ```

```
    Block
    ;
    Identifier : Statement
    StatementExpression ;
    if ParExpression Statement [else Statement] 
    assert Expression [: Expression] ;
    switch ParExpression { SwitchBlockStatementGroups } 
    while ParExpression Statement
    do Statement while ParExpression ;
    for ( ForControl ) Statement
    break [Identifier] ;
    continue [Identifier] ;
    return [Expression] ;
    throw Expression ;
    synchronized ParExpression Block
    try Block (Catches | [Catches] Finally)
    try ResourceSpecification Block [Catches] [Finally]
```

Thus, you can see `while` is followed by `ParExpression` (expression in parentheses) and `Statement`.

For

```
while(true){
    int u =89;
}
```

the `Statement` after of `while`s body expands to `Block` which in turn may expand to a `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`.

For

```
while(true)
    int u =89; // compile time error
```

the `Statement` of `while`s body cannot expand to `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement` as there is no `Block`.

Thus, the 2<sup>nd</sup> simply isn't part of the Java language (based on its grammar).