# Declaring Java variable type in if statement

Tags: java

I have 2 Java classes car and camion (this is just an example). And I would like to initialise a variable "machine" depending on my function input:

```
void printInfo(boolean is_car){
       if(is_car)
                car machine = new car();

       else
                camion machine = new camion();
       
       String info = machine.getInfo();
       String type = machine.type();
       ...

}
```

It seems that I can't use the declared variables outside the if statement.
Is there any solution for that? I would like to avoid putting lot of If statements in my function.

Comment: If they have inheritance relationship you can change a little to make this work. If not, that would be a horrible practice for a strongly typed language, and you should avoid it at all cost.

Comment: The variable would be immediately out of scope, so an if doesn't allow variable declaration (unless enclosed in a block). See also [Compiler error when declaring a variable inside if condition and no curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206618/compiler-error-when-declaring-a-variable-inside-if-condition-and-no-curly-braces)

Answer (score 1):

Declare Vehicle (suppose which is super class of both car and camion) outside of the if block.

```
Vehicle machine;
if (is_car) {
    machine = new car();
} else {
    machine = new camion();
}
```